# Find bunch of Files in inside directory

Tags: java, file, io

Hi I have directory which contains sub directories with names like

```
1-1,
2-3,
4-10,
11-20
```

Now I want to find all the directories in the range say 1-10 so it should return me dirs 1-1,2-3 and 4-10. I have the following code but it not working as expected.

```
File files[] = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {

                String name = file.getName().toLowerCase();

                if (name.startsWith("1-") || name.endsWith("-10"))
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Above code gives output 1-1 and 4-10 it does not include 2-3 in combination. How do I solve this problem? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it easier to split your `name` into a `min` and `max` value and then check your range?

Comment: 2-3 doesn't match the criteria in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match on a numeric criterion, checking the name as a string isn't the correct approach.  As @Perneel said above, what you want to do is parse the directory name to get the range it contains and check those.

```
    File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            try {
                String[] bounds = file.getName().toLowerCase().split("-");
                return (Integer.parseInt(bounds[0]) <= 10 && Integer.parseInt(bounds[1]) >= 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // array index out of bounds & number format exceptions mean 
                // this isn't a directory with the proper name format
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(files)); // 1-1, 2-3, 4-10
```